# Addressing a mixed design analysis of variance when only one of the two groups went under repeated measures?

Tags: anova, mixed-model

so essentially I have 2 groups (A and B, A is a control, and B can be referred to the "expert" group), and group B went under a specific training program (two times points, one prior to the training, and the second being post training). Group A (the controls) only had one testing period, and did not go under the training. A behavioural measure was taken at each testing point (Group A was once, Group B was prior to and post training). Would a mixed design ANOVA be sufficient in investigating the difference between the two groups (including differences between the pre and post training in Group B), even if group A only had one testing point, where group B had two? Or of course, I may be wrong and another test would be more suitable?

Thanks.

Comment: How were the groups defined? By randomization, or preexisting groups?

Answer (score 1):

There is no fair or useful comparison of the difference between the two groups. Go back and measure group A a second time and then you'd have something. Otherwise there's nothing about group A that you can use to test the effect of treatment.

You're asking for a statistical test but the better question is, why would it matter if there's a difference between group A and group B at either time point? Any statistically decisive difference would demonstrate nothing more than they were disparate samples. In the first time period that's all they are and in the second time period there's nothing fair to compare.

Comment: Hi John, thanks for the helpful response. Would there then be anyway to test if the similarity between the group B and group A was greater before or after the training? The initial part of this can be addressed by a t-test, to compare the two groups at the one time point (before any training), but then I was curious if there was any way to test if group B was "more/less" similar to group A following the treatment. Thus, the confusion set it when wanting to make this comparison, but only having the controls at the initial time point, who didn't undergo the same training. Thanks again.

Comment: Did you read the answer at all?

Comment: Yes, so there is no test available then, since as you stated, they are "disparate samples".